# Nullable field in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, boolean, nullable

I have a pure `boolean` type of field in my web-app, but now I am thinking about difference between nullable and non-nullable property.

In which case would I have the best performance: use 'true' and 'false' value or use 'true' and `NULL` instead?

Comment: What do you mean by "best performance"? Why would you think about performance before thinking about what's the most reasonable way? This is not even about this exact thing (there's no possible performance gain for using `null` instead of `false`), it's more about the whole concept of optimizing for performance before identifying the actual performance bottlenecks. Don't *guess* on performance - make your application nice and clean, test it, and if needed, optimize the parts that will make an impact.

Answer (score 1):

The common convention is to use `true` and `false` as values - they mean you know the answer to the question asked. `null` is not a value - it's a lack thereof, and is usually used as such.

E.g., consider the (morbid) column `has_cancer`. `true` means the subject has it, `false` that he does not, and `null` that he has not been tested yet, so we just don't know.

Comment: Can i optimize the db queries if to use null field? Do i have any additional features in this case?

Comment: @Sergey_Ksenofontov You get the awesome features like ANSI NULL behaviour - any operand that is null will propagate to the return value. `1 + NULL` is `NULL`, for example. This usually leads to having to do something like `1 + coalesce(column, 0)` everywhere :) Treat `null` the way it's supposed to be treated - an absence of value, not "yet another value".